# Enumerating singulars mixed with plurals

Tags: articles, zero-article, lists

Suppose we have a picture with several objects that we have to enumerate them. First, is this enumeration correct?

> There is a little girl, two boys, an old man and a pen.

Second, how would we enumerate them if we have to omit the articles? Can we enumerate them like this:

> There are two boys, an old man, little girl and pen.

Comment: In what context would you ***have*** to omit the articles? Your second version is just about credible, but in practice native speakers would be highly unlikely to use it in any contexts at all.

Comment: I see now that I was not clear. I should have said "omit the articles after the first singular" or "have to not repeat the singular article".

Comment: Would the second version still hold true if I enumerate further articles like this: `There are two boys, (an old man, little girl and pen), and three stars, and (a fork and spoon).` Notice the pattern plural singular in the enumeration: P (S) P (S)

Comment: I know what combinations sound "reasonable", and I know certain combinations sound totally unacceptable, but it's more complex than will fit in a comment. Besides which, offhand I don't have conscious knowledge of what "rules" I'm applying. But I'll try to flesh out an actual answer.

Comment: What itches me is that when I break a list of singulars with a plural one, I do not know if I have to start the next singular one with an indefinite article or just continue listing the singular objects without introducing another indefinite article.
Hopefully I managed to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think in such contexts, determiners *(a, an, the, etc.)* are similar to quantifiers *(two, some, etc.)* and standard adjectives *(little, old, etc.)*. Normally, you *must* use one of those before the *first* item in such lists, and obviously if you omit a quantifier or adjective this affects the meaning. But omitting other determiners is a bit more vague.

> 1: *He put a bottle, a glass, and a beer mat on the table.*
>    2: *He put a bottle, glass, and beer mat on the table.*
>    3: *?He put the glass, the beer mat, and the bottle on the table.*
>    4: *??He put the bottle, glass, and a beer mat on the table.*
>    5: *??He put a bottle, two glasses, and beer mat on the table.*
>    6: *??He put a bottle, magazine, and two glasses on the table.*

I don't really think there's any "grammatical rule" against the last two there, but they seem at the very least "stylistically awkward" to me. And #3 is slightly odd (you have to imagine a context where the *specific* bottle, glass, and beer mat have already been identified).

As a rule of thumb, I would suggest it's generally better to include *all* determiners unless the list consists entirely of short (one or two word) elements, and/or those elements are naturally associated in the current context. But if you *do* omit articles, you should probably do so consistently, starting with the second element.

---

Finally, I'll just flag up a peripheral point arising from OP's examples...

> 7: *There are an apple, pear, peach, and banana on the table*
>    8: *?There **is** an apple, pear, peach, and banana on the table*

I don't know if there's a grammatical rule against using the singular verb form in #8, but it doesn't sound quite right to me (people do use the form, though, so OP's first example isn't all *that* bad).

Comment: I understand that this sentence `5: ??He put a bottle, two glasses, and beer mat on the table.` is an example of this suggestion "But if you do omit articles, you should probably do so consistently, starting with the second element."

Comment: As for the sentence `8: ?There is an apple, pear, peach, and banana on the table`, what I know is that one has to use "there is" if the list begins with a singular, and use "there are" if the list begins with a plural.

Comment: I think the singular in number 8 sounds wrong because there are no articles. @FumbleFingers: would "there is an apple, a pear, a peach, and a banana on the table" sound better?

Comment: @Peter,learner: I think in practice native speakers are somewhat divided when it comes to *There is/are* before a list. Personally, I prefer #7 over #8 - but I know both forms occur, and really I don't much like *either* alternative. If I'm writing something like that I usually try to recast into something where there's no scope for disagreement - *"An apple, pear, and banana **are** on the table"*.